# Adding one day to a date border case?

Tags: javascript, date

I don't understand why this code doesn't work. Solutions on SO mention that doing `date.getDate()+1` should add a day but in my case it adds one month and two days?

```
var year = 2014;
var month = 3;
var day = 31;

// creating an actual date
requestedDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
console.debug(requestedDate.toString());
// outputs "Mon Mar 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)"

var d = new Date();
d.setDate(requestedDate.getDate()+1);
console.debug(d.toString());
// outputs "Fri May 02 2014 11:04:52 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
```

Comment: Because month is 0-based. January = 0, February = 1, March = 2, April = 3... Also, `d` is never set to a particular date. `new Date()` equals the current date. Not the same as `requestedDate`.

Comment: Yes I know, this is why I subtract 1 at line 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the second date to the same as the first date.

In the first `new Date()` you're setting the date to 31. march.
The second `new Date()` sets the date to today, 1. april.
`31 + 1 = 32`, and 1. april plus 32 days should be 2. may.

```
var year = 2014;
var month = 3;
var day = 31;

// creating an actual date
requestedDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
console.debug(requestedDate.toString());

var d = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // set the  date to the same
d.setDate(requestedDate.getDate()+1);
console.debug(d.toString());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/RMLFf/)

Comment: Thanks! I thought `setDate()` was enough. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.